# Conditionally comment a block in an Ansible template

Tags: jinja2, ansible-template

Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

I don't want to remove the block via `{% if SSL %}{% endif %}`

```
{% filter comment(
        decoration = (SSL) | ternary('', '#'),
        prefix  = (SSL) | ternary('', '### the following block has been deactivated by ansible via: --skip-tags SSL\n#'),
        postfix = (SSL) | ternary('', '#\n### end of deactivated by ansible via: --skip-tags SSL'))
%}
server {
        listen {{ HTTPS_PORT }} ssl http2 default_server;
        server_name "";
        server_name _;
        return 444;
}
{%- endfilter %}
```